# How are two languages integrated into projects?

Tags: programming-languages, environment

I've been wondering for awhile, how are two languages used in the same project?

Android, for instance. It's based off of the Linux Kernel, but has a Java Environment for applications to run in.

Comment: Too broad. Read http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/

Comment: Apologies. Thank you for the link, I'll get a good read out of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a build system. One of the most commonly available ones is [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). A build system allows you to specify the artifacts needed to proceed along to every step, plus it allows you to set targets. I personally prefer [shakebuild](http://shakebuild.com), but your preferences may vary.

The question of calling e.g. Haskell in Rust is far more difficult. Languages need to define standards of interoperability, which they both adhere to. Often, this means that what is passed between is simply product types, strings, ints, and the like.